# Adding a property to a queryset in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a messaging system and part of what I want to do is based on whether the user is a sender or a receiver of a message, different CSS loads. I'm trying to achieve this by attaching a property to each message object that identifies this.

I have my message

```
#models.py
class Message(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.time_date)

    message_from = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(class)s_message_from")
    message_to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(class)s_message_to")
    message = models.TextField()
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    time_date = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, blank=True, null=True)
```

and my view to get the messages:

```
def view_messages(request):
    messages = Message.objects.filter(message_to=request.user, job_id=None).distinct('message_from')
    messages_from_user_ids = messages.values_list('message_from', flat=True).distinct()

    messages_from_user = User.objects.filter(id__in=messages_from_user_ids)

    messages = Message.objects.filter(
        Q(message_to=request.user) & Q(message_from_id=messages_from_user_ids[0]) & Q(job_id=None) | Q(
            message_from_id=messages_from_user_ids[0]) & Q(
            message_from_id=request.user) & Q(job_id=None)).order_by('time_date')

    messages = Message.objects.annotate(foo='true') # error

    return render(request, 'freelancestudent/general/messages.html', {'messages': messages,
                                                                      'messages_from': messages_from_user})
```

What I was trying to achieve in the line commented error was to simply test [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) by annotating the string `'true'` to every message object, accessible under `foo`. This gives me the error `'str' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'`.

What I'm ultimately trying to achieve, in case I'm going about this the wrong way, is to check if the user is the sender. The idea i had of achieving it was to do something like this:

```
for message in messages:
    if message_from == request.user.id:
        messages.annotate(sender=True)
```

Though, this isn't the right syntax. I'm not sure `annotate` is the right function, either. Any ideas?

Comment: That sounds more like a template design thing.. Do you not need to check there if the message sender is the one looking at it?

Comment: That can be checked in the view through the `request`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are looping through the queryset, don't try to use `annotate`, just set an attribute on the instance.

```
for message in messages:
    if message_from == request.user.id:
        message.sender = True
```

Alternatively, I think you could use `annotate` with [`Case`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case):

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, Case, Value, When

messages = Message.annotate(
    sender=Case(
        When(message_from=request.user, then=Value(True)),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField(),
    )
)
```

Comment: Note that support for conditional expressions is introduced in Django 1.9.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/

Comment: @pygeek I thought they were new in 1.8, which is now the minimum supported version.